# Cannot get the store values in redux

Tags: redux, react-redux

I need 2 objects to save in the store which is user and customer. So I have created actions, reducers, and store like below.

```
export const ADD_USER = "ADD_USER";

export const ADD_CUSTOMER = "ADD_CUSTOMER";
```

This is my action file and my reducer is like below

```
import { ADD_USER, EDIT_USER } from '../actions';

 const userReducer = (state = [], action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ADD_USER:
      state.user = {...state.user, user: action.payload};
      return state

    default:
      return state;
  }
}

export default userReducer;
```

And this is my root reducer

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import userReducer from './user';
import customerReducer from './customer';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  user: userReducer,
  customer: customerReducer
});

export default rootReducer;
```

I have called the reducer like this

```
store.dispatch({
      type: ADD_USER,
      payload: user,
    })
```

It is working fine. But If I need to get the data from the store so that I need to call like this

```
let store = store.getState();
console.log(store.user) is not working
console.log(store.user.user) is working.
```

How to avoid this nested level. I need to get user from store like this

```
store.user
```

Could anyone help to resolve this issue?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

There is a problem because in your rootReducer you created **user** parameter inside **state**. After that you trying to add another **user** parameter inside your **userReducer**. That is why you create problem with nested object.

Easy way to solve it:

```
import { ADD_USER, EDIT_USER } from '../actions';

const userReducer = (state = [], action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ADD_USER:
      state.user = {...state, action.payload};   //there is a fix
      return state

    default:
      return state;
  }
}

export default userReducer;
```

Answer (score 1):

You should return a new whole state inside your reducer, to do so update your reducer file like this

```js
import { ADD_USER, EDIT_USER } from '../actions';

 const userReducer = (state = [], action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ADD_USER:
      return {
        ...state,
        user: action.payload
      }
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

export default userReducer;
```